# Notepad++ поиск и замена регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть исходная строка: `abcd_12345:abc`

Нужно, чтобы получилось так: `abcd_12345:12345abc`

Т.е., взять то, что находится после `"_"` и подставить перед `"abc"`.
Поиск самой строки я делал так: (в Notepad++) `^[A-z0-9]*[_][A-z0-9].*$`

Я понимаю, что в том же Notepad++ мне нужно найти: `^[A-z0-9]*[_][A-z0-9].*$`.
Заменить на что?

Текст до `"_"` и после будет разный, ровно как и после `":"`. Но суть остаётся в том, чтобы брать значение после `"_"` и подставлять его после `":"`.

Comment: Группу, которую хотите "перенести", оберните круглыми скобками. А подставить группу можно указав её порядковый номер `\1`. Это есть во втором примере их документации http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Example_2

Comment: `^([A-Za-z0-9]+_)([A-Za-z0-9]+):` => `$1$2:$2`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]+_)([A-Za-z0-9]+):
```

Замените на `$1$2:$2`.

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `([A-Za-z0-9]+_)` - Подмаска №1 (`$1`): один и более буквоцифровых символов, а после них знак подчёркивания
- `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` - Подмаска №2 (`$2`): один и более буквоцифровых символов
- `:` - двоеточие.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно подойдет и такая регулярка - `(?<=_)(\d+):`. Замена будет выглядеть так `$1:$1`.

```js
const str = 'abcd_12345:abc'
const re = /(?<=_)(\d+):/g
console.log(str.replace(re, '$1:$1'))
```